# Creating a custom ActiveRecord association `has_many_tagged` that extends `has_many`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I'm trying to devise this querying mechanism in which I have models associated to a `Tag` model (with a polymorphic association `as: taggable`) such that when I run a: modelA.modelBs it would check if `modelA` instance and `modelBs` association `responds_to?(:tags)` and so filter the query by the intersection of tags.

Example

```
# modelA_instance1.tags == [1, 4, 9]
# modelA_instance2.tags == [2, 3]
# modelB_instance1.tags == [1, 2]
# modelB_instance2.tags == [4]
expect(modelA_instance1.modelBs).to contain_exactly([modelB_instance1, modelB_instance2])
expect(modelA_instance2.modelBs).to contain_exactly([modelB_instance1])
```

But ideally I want it to be seamless, without the need to have to define the `has_many :modelBs` with a scope joining the `:tags` model

Is that possible? Could I override a (or some) getters of ActiveRecord to make this?

Or perhaps I could create something that extends on `has_many` like `has_many_tagged :modelBs`

```
def has_many_tagged(... scope ...)
  # extend scope with join on tags and call original has_many
end
```

Comment: Show your current `has_many` defenition.

Comment: Has many is a method from ActiveRecord::Association::ClassMethods

Comment: I just remebmered that acts_as_paranoid does a similar kind of magic! I’ll check their code